# Align numerical precision Excel 2013 and R

Tags: r, excel

It is a rather broad question, but I replicated an Excel model in R. R produces almost the same results as excel, but there is always a slight % deviation in the range of 10^-8. I assume this is due to numerical precision. The model uses only basic arithmetic operations. 
My question would be: is there a simple way to force R to use the same numerical precision as Excel?

Comment: No more than you could force a butterfly to flap its wings in sync with a wasp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not.  R always uses double-precision (i.e., 8-byte) floating point, and and it seems [that's also what Excel uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel).

It is indeed mildly surprising that the results are not identical if you're only doing simple arithmetic, but note that even changing the sequence of arithmetic operations can change the results (i.e., floating-point arithmetic is not associative: `(a+b)+c != a+(b+c)`, so if arithmetic is done left-to-right, `a+b+c != c+b+a`). It's probably impossible to even know what Excel is doing under the hood, although [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113) (which may? only apply to Excel 2003) states points at which Excel deviates from the IEEE 754 standard used by R and most other numerical programs.

You *might* be able to get exact equality by working up from simple to more complex examples, seeing where the divergence occurs, and rearranging your computations to avoid the problem, but unless this equality is extremely important to you/worth investing a lot of effort, you may be better off testing for approximate equality.

It's conceivable that export to CSV is losing precision (e.g. see [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/interesting-excel-behavior-csv-numerical-accuracy/28543e16-78e9-4afe-ae64-f9bb412c9039?auth=1)).

Comment: So there is nothing I can do like changing the format of my data frame at the start, when I read in the data from Excel? I thought about comparing the data at the beginning with the original excel to see if something goes wrong already at the first step. I only do simple arithmetic operations (I assume exponents or roots are still considered simple?). Could the export to CSV pose a problem? 
Otherwise, I will mark it as answered, even though it is not the answer I was looking for.